# Does SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition trial version supports clustering and auditing?

Tags: sql-server-2008, cluster-computing, audit

I am going to download SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition trial version, my doubt is does this trial version fully functional or some limited functionalities?

Does it supports Audit and Clustering features?

Comment: can you be civil and not swear at/badmouth others in Hindi or Urdu. There are people here other than you who do speak the language.

Answer (score 0):

It is fully functional for a limited period of time (90 days? 180 days? Can't remember)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does - last I checked.

You might also want to take a look at the developer's edition - it is basically the same as Enterprise edition - but for development purposes only.

Comment: but it does not supports audit feature.

Comment: I guess it does. Look here http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx . It does say that it is an specialized version of EE. Or look here http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/developer.aspx